# Cant find CPTNativeEvent class

Tags: core-plot

I updated my project to use core plot 1.0 plot but i can't find CPTNativeEvent class.

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index withEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
```

If I search for CPTNativeEvent in http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/, the class is there.

But if i search for it in my CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj, it isn't there.

I downloaded the core plot 1.0 from http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typedef. It equates to `UIEvent` on iOS and `NSEvent` on the Mac. It is defined in **CPTPlatformSpecificDefines.h**, visible in the "iPhone only" folder in the Xcode project.

Comment: I know Eric. The problem is because my CPTPlatformSpecificDefines.h file doesn't have this typedef there. In my file only have defined typedef UIImage CPTNativeImage;

Ive already downloaded twice the core plot 1.0 from google code

Comment: That was added after the 1.0 release. See [this revision](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=7c559d7a7a5a1e81c4a0e9e4e1d1b7dfa7c81f91).